# Vue-Grid-Layout responsive components when the resolution is reduced

Tags: vue.js, grid-layout

I have a Dashboard that is made with Vue-Grid-Layout and it contains bunch of other components, I used 2 different grid layouts, one is for my cards and the other one is for my widgets. I dont want my cards to be dragged and replaced somewhere that should my widgets be, so I separated them into two layouts. Here is my html looks like;

```
<div class="row" v-if="isCardsActive">
        <grid-layout 
          :layout.sync="cardsLayout"
          :col-num="12"
          :row-height="25"
          :is-draggable="draggable"
          :is-resizable="resizable"
          :vertical-compact="true"
          :use-css-transforms="true"
          :responsive="true"
        >
          <grid-item 
            v-for="(item, index) in cardsLayout" :key="index"
            :x="item.x"
            :y="item.y"
            :w="item.w"
            :h="item.h"
            :i="item.i"
            drag-allow-from=".vue-draggable-handle"
            drag-ignore-from=".no-drag"
          >
            <component v-if="item.isActive" :is="item.c"></component>
          </grid-item>
        </grid-layout>
      </div>
      <!-- Widgets -->
      <div class="row" v-if="isWidgetsActive">
        <grid-layout 
          :layout.sync="layout"
          :col-num="12"
          :row-height="30"
          :is-draggable="draggable"
          :is-resizable="resizable"
          :vertical-compact="true"
          :use-css-transforms="true"
          :responsive="true"
        >
          <grid-item 
            v-for="(item, index) in layout" :key="index"
            :x="item.x"
            :y="item.y"
            :w="item.w"
            :h="item.h"
            :i="item.i"
            drag-allow-from=".vue-draggable-handle"
            drag-ignore-from=".no-drag"
          >
            <component v-if="item.isActive" :is="item.c"></component>
          </grid-item>
        </grid-layout>
```

I have two arrays for layouts which are `cardsLayout` and `widgetsLayout`, here is my data;

```
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Dashboard",
      items: [
        {
          text: "Dashboard",
          active: true,
        },
      ],
      isCardsActive: true,
      cardsLayout: [
        {"x":0,"y":0,"w":3,"h":4,"i":"0", "c": 'ManagedDevices', isActive: true}, 
        {"x":3,"y":0,"w":3,"h":4,"i":"1", "c": 'ActiveEndpoints', isActive: true},
        {"x":6,"y":0,"w":3,"h":4,"i":"2", "c": 'RoutingTraffic', isActive: true},  
        {"x":9,"y":0,"w":3,"h":4,"i":"3", "c": 'BridgingTraffic', isActive: true}, 
      ],
      isWidgetsActive: true,
      layout: [
        {"x":0,"y":0,"w":12,"h":13,"i":"0", "c": 'TrafficOverview', isActive: true},
        {"x":0,"y":0,"w":4,"h":10.7,"i":"1", "c": 'TopManagedDevices', isActive: true},
        {"x":4,"y":0,"w":4,"h":10.7,"i":"2", "c": 'WirelessChannels', isActive: true},
        {"x":8,"y":0,"w":4,"h":10.47,"i":"3", "c": 'DeviceAlarms', isActive: true},
      ],
      draggable: true,
      resizable: false,
      index: 0
    };
  },
```

I put my components inside these arrays, there are two other functions that checks if the components are active or deactive based on user selections but I didn't put them here to my question because they are irrelevant to it.

What I want to do is, showing and hiding these components based on user's selections and made a widget logic for myself. The user will allow to select and deselect cards and components to be represented in the dashboard. But here is the thing;

Let's say the user doesn't want to see any cards at the top of his dashboard so he deselected all of them, the `grid-layout` for cards will still be there because I only change the element of an array's property which is `isActive`.

I also created another function that checks if all the elements of cards array's `isActive` property is false, It goes and makes `isCardsActive` false. And as you can see in my HTML, I show cards grid-layout only when `isCardsActive` true. In this way I can remove the cards grid-layout when there is no card in the dashboard.

But I need a similar logic for widgetsLayout. There are 4 components in widgetsLayout array and user is also allowed to hide and show them in the dashboard. But the thing is, If a component or a widget is deselected by user, it isn't being showed on the dashboard but its grid-layout is still there and taking up some huge spaces in the dashboard. I can't use `v-if` for widget layout because they are all in the same grid-layout.

The other part of my question is, when resolution is reduced, in smaller devices, tablets and phones, the responsiveness is kind of problematic. I don't declare any `col-md-6` or something in the component's HTML itself, because I declare the heights, widths, coordinates, columns etc. in the layout arrays.

For example, when the page is full, 4 cards appear side by side in a row. So one of them takes 3 of 12 basically. But when the resolution is reduced, they appear on silly positions in the layout.

What I want to do is, if the device is smaller, like a tablet or a mobile phone, Cards should be appear not in a row but a column with `col-md-12` size. So I should define this in a more dynamic way.

I know it is been a long question but If there is anyone who's been working with Vue-Grid-Layout, I think my work and my question should help others if it's answered properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find out resolution problem?